# Flagging is very slow using the android app

Tags: support, bug, flags, android-app, user-experience

From my experience the android app responds fast, but retrieving the flagging options is time consuming. Also the `Flag submitted` feedback has several seconds delay, with no exception.

Is anyone having the same issue?

I believe this was faster earlier this year (first quarter) and it would be beneficial for the user experience and the motivation to flag questions or answers if the performance could be improved.

Comment: I haven't tried flagging, but the request to close is very, very slow to present the options for vote to close.